# Covariant derivative $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma}$ of constrained velocity vector $\dot{\gamma}$ by distribution $B$ and bounded map $\delta_i$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I have been studying differential geometry for a while. The subject is hard to grasp at first, but gets easier once one understands the main concepts. One of them are covariant derivative $\nabla_X Y$. I have been working on Classic Mechanics with Euler-Lagrange.

Oftentimes, the velocity vector $\dot{\gamma}$ gets constrained by some distribution-spanned vectors $b_j$ . For this case, I am aware by [1] that the covariant derivative $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma}$ belongs to annihilator space $a_i$ i.e. $a_i \lambda^i$, such that vectors $\langle a_i, b_j \rangle = 0$. This allows me to obtain to timeseries $\dot{p}$.

However, for the motivation of physical slippage, it may occur the condition $\langle a_i, \dot{\gamma} \rangle = \delta_i$, which leads to velocity vector $\dot{\gamma} = b_j p^j + \mu^+ \delta$, for Moore-Penrose matrix symbol $+$ under usage, and matrix entry $\mu_{kl}$ given by $\langle a_k, e_l \rangle$, and unitary vector $e_l$.

My question is: which condition may the covariant derivative fulfill? As on previous case, it should belong to distribution $A$, annihilator to $B$.

The best I can wonder so far is, the covariant derivative $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma}$ spans as a sum $a_i\lambda^i + d$, for vector $d$ discovered to be. From these, velocity vector $\dot{\gamma}$ corresponds to vector sum $b_j p^j + c$, its derivative $\ddot{\gamma}$ is $(L_{b_k} b_j) p^k p^j + (L_{b_k} c) p^k + c_t$ and we may substitute on equality $\langle b_j, \nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma} \rangle = \langle b_j, \ddot{\gamma} + \Gamma_{kj} p^k p^j \rangle = \langle b_j, d \rangle$. But what is vector $d$?? I am overwhelmed. :-/

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

[1] Lewis, Andrew D. Affine connections and distributions with applications to nonholonomic mechanics.